# Trying to recall a sci-fi story about sounds from space

Tags: story-identification

The premises is:

A radio station broadcasted sounds recorded from deep space and those sounds when amplified provided people with a blissful trance.
And it ended with the protagonist cursing the find and people abusing it, but then the radio comes on and he is blissfully happy again.

It's a short story and felt like Vonnegut-style. Sorry I can't add comments yet, I will be updating this question.

Comment: Short story? Novella? Novel?

Comment: Not this, but similar premise; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_the_Spheres_(The_Outer_Limits)

Comment: You know, given the broadness of the title, I'm not sure there's any value in this question being here. You asked the question 14 hours ago, spent a few hours googling (which probably should have been spent before asking the question), and then answered it yourself. Perhaps the question should be removed?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I searched for a long while before I asked the question. And the only reason I found it is because of lucky guess to search for a Russian quote from the Russian translation of the text. But by all means remove this as useless

Comment: I have no authority to close--just thinking out loud :-) Glad you found your answer regardless, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. It was by Vonnegut indeed.

[*"The Euphio Question by Kurt Vonnegut"*](http://aofisonfire.blogspot.com/2007/08/euphio-question.html)

It begins with :

> "Lew, Fred, and I found peace of mind by sitting in easy chairs and turning on a gadget the size of a table-model television set. No herbs, no golden rule, no muscle control, no sticking our noses in other people's troubles to forget our own; no hobbies, Taoism[I1] , push-ups or contemplation of a lotus. The gadget is, I think, what a lot of people vaguely foresaw as the crowning achievement of civilization: an electronic something-or-other, cheap, easily mass-produced, that can, at the flick of a switch, provide tranquillity. I see you have one here."

and ends with

> "In closing, I'd like to point out that Lew Harrison, the would-be
>   czar of euphio, is an unscrupulous person, unworthy of public trust.
>   It wouldn't surprise me, for instance, if he had set the clockwork on
>   this sample euphio set so that its radiations would addle your
>   judgments when you are trying to make a decision. In fact, it seems to
>   be whirring suspiciously at this very moment, and I'm so happy I could
>   cry. I've got the swellest little kid and the swellest bunch of
>   friends and the swellest old wife in the world. And good old Lew
>   Harrison is the salt of the earth, believe me. I sure wish him a lot
>   of good luck with his new enterprise."

Comment: Could you add details of how it meets the criteria? Even though it is your own question, it can help other viewers understand *why* the answer fits :)

Comment: @Richard thanks for editing the quotes in. This story made a huge impression on me when I read it as a kid. And it is pretty relevant today.